# POP up (Sign IN & Create New Account ) Problem

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, theme, login

we use theme claue 
we faced problem in POP up (Sign IN & Create New Account ) as per attached image Create New Account loading & Sign IN get error (could not authenticate. please try again later) while i use the login account page everything is working well , so kindly advice

https://i.ibb.co/X3vDDwm/2019-12-05-123918.jpg

https://i.ibb.co/cCy2CcT/2019-12-05-1234551.jpg

Comment: Using 3rd party module?

Comment: same issue I am facing any luck?